# Prevent accidental clicks on Google Map APi attribution/logo in mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, rhomobile

I have built a mobile app using Rhomobile, jQuery Mobile and Google Maps API. Some users accidentally click on the Google logo and attribution links at the bottom of the map. Is there a way to prevent such accidental links and/or catch them and ask the user if they actually want to leave the app?

Here is an example of the layout of the app: http://www.mycoursewalk.com/mobile_course_walk/course_view/152

Open it on a mobile phone to better see the issue.

Thanks,

Nick,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this without breaking the [Terms of Service](http://developers.google.com/maps/terms).